# The current user id could not be determined Error in Dynamics crm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-4

We are getting "The current user id could not be determined.".

We have take a back up and restore on UAT with different Name 'OrgDataMigration' not like 'ORG_MSCRM'.

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more explanation where did you get that error message? How to reproduce the error?

Have you check whether the user that mapped within the UAT is available in UAT domain controller?